# How to access the index of a list for the colorfunction of a listplot?

Tags: plotting, color, style

From the documentation of ListPlot,

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 
Pi, Pi/20}],PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

Varies the color of the plotted points based on their position in the list, ie the parametric 'time' variable t.

However,

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 
Pi, Pi/20}], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

keeps the color of the 'joined' fixed. Is there a way to make it vary too? I know of 'Colorfunction', but according to the documentation, it can in the case of a Listplot only be defined as function of x and y, not of 't'. Im fine with either through interpolation, or just keeping the color of the previous datapoint.

Comment: Please define ```Nt, Np, lw, Y```.

Comment: @Syed have done so

Comment: I mean, please provide definitions as well as a minimal example; such that when executed, this code produces a plot. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed significantly simplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coords = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];
```

#### 1. GraphicsComplex + VertexColors

```
Graphics[
   GraphicsComplex[
     coords, 
    {AbsolutePointSize[7], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
     Point[Range@Length@coords, VertexColors -> Automatic], 
     Line[Range@Length@coords, VertexColors -> Automatic]}, 
    VertexColors -> Table[Hue[t/(2 Pi)], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}]], 
  Axes -> True]
```

[image]

#### 2. MeshStyle + VertexColors

```
meshStyle = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  # /. Point[x : {_, __}] :> 
 Through[{Line, Point}[x, 
     VertexColors -> Map[Hue]@Subdivide[-1 + Length[x]]]]} &;

ListPlot[coords, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[7], 
 Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> meshStyle]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! any idea why the second approach (at least) does not work when replacing Hue[]? by Opacity[]?

Comment: I figured that I can replace Hue by Function[{o},Directive[Red,Opacity[o]]] for example, but the problem is it still plots the original Joined->true lines in Blue too, which thus become visible. I can set these to white using PlotStyle, but don't see how to make them transparent or make them disappear without affecting the Mesh too?

Comment: something like `meshStyle = {AbsoluteThickness[2], # /. 
     Point[x : {_, __}] :> {LineOpacity -> 1, 
       Through[{Line, Point}[x, 
         VertexColors -> 
          Map[Opacity[#, Hue@#] &]@Subdivide[-1 + Length[x]]]]}} &; 
ListPlot[coords, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> meshStyle, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[LineOpacity -> 0, AbsolutePointSize[7]]]`?

Comment: Genius! does the job, thanks

Answer (score 4):

One way could be the following. This requires that points be relatively close to one another or the plot will have jagged lines.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
cols = Table[Hue[t/(2 π)], {t, 0, 2 π, π/20}];
segs = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/20}];
linesegs = Partition[segs, 2, 1];
Dimensions /@ {Most@cols, linesegs}
```

> {{40}, {40, 2, 2}}

```
p1 = ListPlot[
   Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 π)]], {t, 0, 
     2 π, π/20}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]];

g1 = Graphics[{
    MapThread[{#1, Line[#2]} &, {Most@cols, linesegs}]
    }
   ];
    
Show[p1, g1]
```

[image]

---

Or put contents of `g1` inside an `Epilog` statement (same result):

```
p2 = ListPlot[
  Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 π)]], {t, 0, 
    2 π, π/20}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]
  , Epilog -> {
    MapThread[{#1, Line[#2]} &, {Most@cols, linesegs}]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pts = Table[
   Style[{{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, {Cos[t + Pi/20], Sin[2 (t + Pi/20)]}}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], 
   {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];

Show[ListPlot[pts], ListLinePlot[pts]]
```

[image]

Comment: This one is nice in its simplicity